# error: incompatible types: CAP#1 cannot be converted to int[] (Java, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I have

```
int [] nr_modes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.NOISE_REDUCTION_AVAILABLE_NOISE_REDUCTION_MODES);
```

And I want to change it to

```
for (CameraCharacteristics.Key <?> key : characteristics.getKeys()) {
    check = key.getName();
    check = check.toLowerCase();
    if (check.contains("noise")){
       int []   modes = characteristics.get(key)
    }
```

This is for debugging as I have some keys I cannot access by characteristics.NAME_HERE, which they themselves are also keys.

The error is
error: incompatible types: CAP#1 cannot be converted to int[]
int [] modes = characteristics.get(key);
^
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering, I fixed this problem by casting to an int

from

```
int []   modes = characteristics.get(key);
```

to

```
int []   modes = (int[]) characteristics.get(key);
```